# Let W be the set of matrices in M22(R) with a trace of 0. Show W is a subspace of M22(R).

Tags: linear-algebra

I started by proving that the matrix W is a subspace by verifying the Axioms.
[image]

However, I do not know how to show that the matrix W has a trace 0.
Thank you!

Comment: Probable duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2118979/the-set-of-n-times-n-matrices-having-trace-equal-to-zero-is-a-subspace-of-m?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You only have to prove it satisfies 2 axioms, not all of them.
The first is that the sum of 2 matrices in W is also in W. 
Take 2 matrices with trace 0, so diagonal x, -x for the first, and diagonal y, -y for the second. The sum has diagonal x+y, -x-y which has sum 0, so it has trace 0. 
You can't prove a matrix in W has sum 0, you must assume it.
Second axiom to check is that a scalar multiple of a matrix in W also lies in W.